# I want to bind Wildfly to my IP address using intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly

I want to bind my Wildfly server to my IP address using intellij

My IP is 192.168.56.1

Where do I set this using Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your Jboss run configuration, go to `Startup/Connection` tab and uncheck `Use default` on `Startup script:` input field.
Then just add argument `-b <your ip here>` after `standalone.sh`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. On windows this file is called standalone.bat